# Is the binomial coefficient linear?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider the binomial coefficient

B = $\frac {(c + n -1)!}{c!(n-1)!}$

If we increase the value of c, will we always get a higher value B?
Likewise, if we increase the value of n, will we always get a higher value B?

I want to graph this, but i don't know how to accomplish that. So my question is, is the coefficient linear depending on the values of c and n?

Comment: If $n=1$ then regardless how you change $c$ the result will always equal $1$ since $\frac{c!}{c!}=1$ for all values of $c$.  If $n>1$, yes, you will find that increasing $c$ increases the result.  Similarly, if $c=0$ regardless the value of $n$ you will have the result be equal to $1$ since $\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1)!}=1$ for all values of $n$.

Comment: To visualize these thing, your best bet is to use Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Notice that $$\frac{\binom {n+1}k}{\binom nk}=\frac{n+1}{n+1-k}=1+\frac k{n+1-k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Increasing $c$ or $n$ will increase $B$, as you are going down Pascal's triangle by doing so. However, the one-variable function obtained by fixing $c$ or $n$ is *not linear* unless $c=1$ or $n-1=1$.

$\binom nk$ for fixed $k$ is a polynomial of degree $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$\log(B)=\log \left(\frac{(c+n-1)!}{c! (n-1)!}\right)=\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (c+n)}{\Gamma (c+1) \Gamma (n)}\right)$$ and admit that $c$ is a continous variable, you havr
$$\frac {B'} B=H_{c+n-1}-H_c >0$$ So, $B$ increases with $c$.